# how to apply touch event in image view

Tags: objective-c

I am beginner of iPhone I have working on touch event. I have put this code but in that touch is not perform in image view I have also use scrollview on imageView so that reason in that not apply the touch event.

my code is

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    // get touch event
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if ([touch view] == imagedisplay) {
        // move the image view
        imagedisplay.center = touchLocation;
    }

}
```

but in that not perform the touch event give any suggestion any source code

Comment: what are you saying?
Please use proper english and explain properly

Answer (score 0):

You may use UIGestureRecognizer.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* Tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageViewTapDetected:)];
[Tap setDelegate:self];
[Tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[ImageView addGestureRecognizer:Tap];
```

After that in your function you may determine current tap state by using state function:

```
-(void)imageViewTapDetected:(UItapGestureRecognizer*)Tap{

    switch ([Tap state]) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible:

            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:


            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:


            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:


            break;
        default:

            break;
    }
}
```